# Sorting Arabic words in android

Tags: android

I have a list of Arabic words.

> الأَحَد, الاِثنَين, الثُّلاثاء, الأَربِعاء, الخَميس, الجُمعة,السَّبت

How can I sort it (sort by alphabet) ?

---

updated :

how can I set arrabicCollator to Collections ?

```
    Locale arrabic= new Locale("ar");
    Collator arrabicCollator = Collator.getInstance(arrabic);

    Collections.sort(arr_items, new Comparator<Helper>() {


        @Override
        public int compare(Helper one, Helper two) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return one.getTitle().compareTo(two.getTitle());
        }

    });
```

**solved :**

```
    Locale arabic = new Locale("ar");
    final Collator arabicCollator = Collator.getInstance(arabic);


    Collections.sort(arr_items, new Comparator<Helper>() {


        @Override
        public int compare(Helper one, Helper two) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return arabicCollator.compare(one.getTitle(), two.getTitle());
        }

    });
```

`helper` is a class that include setter and getter functions and `arr_items` is an array if helper :

> ArrayList arr_items = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: what do you mean? how is it different from sorting any other list of words?

Comment: you mean alphabet sort ?

Comment: sort by word? by line? by paragraph? by letters?

Comment: I have seen below link before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949074/sorting-arabic-words-in-java but I cannot implement it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use Collator class. check the [sdk document](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/Collator.html) for it. Also check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9261379/604876)

Comment: tnx, updated myquestion : how can I set arrabicCollator to Collections ?