# How can I sort List<Object> by String value (Persian Alphabet)?

Tags: java, android

I have a List of Student with tow fields (name & number), I want to sort the List by name (Persian name) but When I sort the List with *Collections.sort* there is problem with some Persian Alphabet like "ک" & "گ" & "ژ" &...
   The result is: "ی"  ,  "ک"  ,  "م" 
   But it must be: "ی"  ,  "م"  ,  "ک"

Here is my code:

```
 public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int number;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", number=" + number +
                '}';
    }

}
```

public class Main {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

            List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

            Student temp1 = new Student();
            temp1.setName("ی");
            temp1.setNumber(5);

            Student temp2 = new Student();
            temp2.setName("م");
            temp2.setNumber(4);

            Student temp3 = new Student();
            temp3.setName("ک");
            temp3.setNumber(3);

            studentList.add(temp1);
            studentList.add(temp2);
            studentList.add(temp3);

            // before sort
            System.out.println("before sort");
            for(Student student : studentList){
                    System.out.println("Student name: " + student.getName());
            }

            Locale locale = new Locale("fa");

            System.out.println("--------------------");
            System.out.println("Language: " + locale.getDisplayLanguage());
            System.out.println("--------------------");

            if (studentList.size() > 0) {
                    Collections.sort(studentList, new Comparator<Student>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(final Student object1, final Student object2) {
                                    return Collator.getInstance(locale).compare(object1.getName(), object2.getName());
                            }
                    } );
            }

            // after sort
            System.out.println("after sort");
            for(Student student : studentList){
                    System.out.println("Student name: " + student.getName());
            }

    }
```

}

Comment: Use `Set<Object>` and a `Comparator` instead of a list

Answer (score 3):

You can use a collator, take a look at this:

[Performing Locale-Independent Comparisons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/locale.html)

[Sorting arabic words in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16949074/sorting-arabic-words-in-java)

Or create your own Comparator. Here the doc.

[Object Ordering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)

The reason you are getting those strings sorted in that way is that strings are sorted using the UTF-16 char table. So in UTF-16 those characters are:

- م     ARABIC LETTER MEEM (U+0645)
- ک     ARABIC LETTER KEHEH (U+06A9)
- ی     ARABIC LETTER FARSI YEH (U+06CC)

Comment: It works by English but on Persian or Arabic doesn't work truly.

Answer (score 2):

Use Collator with a new locate for "IR" :

```
Collator.getInstance(new Locale("fa", "IR")).compare ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If such a Locale is not available in the JDK, most likely someone has already written such a library for Java. I didn't find any libraries, but maybe you can find one when you know the language.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of G3ntle_Man answer, if you use Java 8 this can be done using stream() like this

```
mStringList.stream().sorted(
                        (string1, string2) -> Collator.getInstance(
                                new Locale("fa", "IR"))
                                .compare(string1, string2)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```